# PKPaymentRequest not enforcing phone requirement for billing address

Tags: ios, applepay

We are creating a `PKPaymentRequest` and setting the `requiredBillingAddressFields` property to `PKAddressFieldPostalAddress | PKAddressFieldPhone`. The system enforces the address requirement but *ignores the phone requirement*. (Enforce in this case means, disallow the Apple Pay transaction from proceeding until the user has filled in the fields.)

Our app does not require a shipping address, but while debugging we set the `requiredShippingAddressFields` property to `PKAddressFieldPostalAddress | PKAddressFieldPhone` and found the phone number requirement is now enforced.

Nothing in the `PKPaymentRequest` or `PKAddressField` documentation suggests that this is expected behavior. Any ideas on how to work around this?

Edit - here's the full method:

```
+ (PKPaymentRequest *)newPayRequestFromBasket:(WFBasket *)basket
{
    PKPaymentRequest *request = [PKPaymentRequest new];
    request.supportedNetworks = [WFApplePayManager supportedPaymentNetworks];
    request.countryCode = [WFAppTargetDispatcher currentAppTarget].storeConfig.countryCode;
    request.currencyCode = [WFAppTargetDispatcher currentAppTarget].storeConfig.currencyCode;
    request.merchantIdentifier = [WFAppTargetDispatcher currentAppTarget].storeConfig.merchantIdentifier;
    request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS; // Support of 3DS is mandatory

    int64_t orderId = basket.orderId;
    request.applicationData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&orderId length:sizeof(orderId)];

    request.paymentSummaryItems = [WFApplePayManager allSummaryItemsFromBasket:basket];

    request.requiredBillingAddressFields = [WFApplePayManager requiredBillingFields]; // = PKAddressFieldPostalAddress | PKAddressFieldPhone

    return request;
}
```

Comment: please share the code how u r creating a request....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API is a little confusing, but the billing address is just that - the billing address. It doesn't have a phone field. If you want to obtain a user's phone number you should use `requiredShippingAddressFields` instead.

Comment: This is the conclusion we reached. When specifying only `PKAddressFieldPhone` for `requiredShippingAddressFields` the payment sheet just adds a "Contact" row that prompts the user to enter a phone number. We then grab the number from the `shippingAddress` property of `PKPayment`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much documentation for Swift if you need to require multiple shipping fields.  Here's the code to do it.

Swift 3

```
var pkAddress = PKAddressField()
pkAddress.insert(.name)
pkAddress.insert(.email)
request.requiredShippingAddressFields = pkAddress
```